# In Canada how much are child care receipts worth for income tax?

Tags: canada, child-care, tax-credit

How much can my family expect to save on taxes if we ask our sitter for a receipt for last year? Our kids are 6 and 10 and we paid about $2300 last year for occasional child care. My husband and I both work, though my hours were irregular/part time. Are the savings worth it?

{Sorry I didn't say earlier}: I live in Ontario, my husband made near $58000 and I made near $22000.

Answer (score 4):

The tax benefit from deducting child-care expenses is based on the **marginal** (top) tax rate, because you exclude the amount from your net income.  But it is the spouse with **the lower net income** who has to take the deduction.

$22,000 puts you in the **15%** federal bracket and the **6.05%** Ontario bracket, so you'll save **21%** of the claimed amount or approximately **$500**.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your tax bracket, you'll save approximate $700 in taxes.

Comment: How do you calculate that?